# Apache can't read my environment variables

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables

I created an environment variable called API_KEY on my linux server, when I run the following command on php, I get false, meaning there is no variable with that name.

`$api = getenv("API_KEY");`

I created the variable following this steps:

created a keys.sh file in /etc/profile.d/ and saved my variable with this format API_KEY="my variable value"

When I run the "printenv" command as user-ec2 or root I can see the environment variable is there, but what it seems to be the problem is that when apache tries to access it dosen´t show up, I don´t know what to do so that the apache user can find this variable.

Comment: Check what user both of these are running as.

Comment: Apache (at least in some installations) cleans the environment before starting up. That said, please read the description of the "linux" tag and then remove it, rather replace it with "apache". Also, this is not a programming question, so it is better suited to e.g. superuser.com.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Where can I find the "linux" tag so I can read an replace it?

Comment: @NigelRen I have this on my httpd.conf file https://imgur.com/a/Sp9VTrk

Comment: The tags are below your question, they contain various categories that apply to your question. Currently, the tags are "php", "linux" and "environment-variables". Use [edit] to change them.

Answer (score 3):

I went to etc/httpd/conf, where my httpd.conf file was located and created the environment variables using:

`SetEnv API_KEY API_KEY_VALEU`

Now the apache user could return the environment variable when I used:

`getenv('API_KEY');`